# How to handle the Direction of printing grid panel in ext.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing, ext.net

I'm using a grid panel in my web page ..
i added a toolbar contains printing button in the grid panel to print the content of the grid view ..
**the layout direction of the grid is from Right to Left (RTL) to be suitable with arabic ..**

but when i press on the button (print) the grid direction appeared from left to right , which is not correct ..

< ext:Button ID="btnPrintPageGrid" runat="server" Text="طباعة الصفحة الحالية فقط" Icon="Printer" Handler="this.up('grid').print({currentPageOnly : true  });" />

i searched for any option to add to the functionality of the button , but i didn't find, also i tried to add (rtl : true) , but it doesn't work...

Any help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use for printing ms report viewer and recommend you. 
Make a qualitative report on the aspx page and show it in a frame in the pop up window. 
And there is alignment problems do not happen.

Or build report as html and also insert it into the frame. 
Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/D4K3E/1/,
here is the code:

```
ShowPrintWindow = function (frameUrl, title, width, height, hidePrintButton) {
    height = height ? height : 509;
    width = width ? width : 675;
    if (typeof (title) == 'undefined') title = 'Печать';
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        id: 'printWindow',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        autoDestroy: true,
        title: title,
        iconCls: 'icon-printer',
        modal: true,
        items: [{
            border: false,
            html: '<iframe id="printFrame" src="' + 
            frameUrl + 
            '" width="' + 
            (width - 12) + 
            '" height="' + 
            (height - 61) + 
            '" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
        }],
        layout: 'fit',
        buttons: [{
            iconCls: 'icon-printer',
            text: 'Print',
            hidden: hidePrintButton ? true : false,
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    fn: function (item, e) {
                        printIframe('printFrame');
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Close',
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    fn: function (item, e) {
                        Ext.getCmp('printWindow').close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }).show();
};

function printIframe(id) {
    var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
    var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
    iframe.focus();
    ifWin.print();
    return false;
}
```

[image]